# [exacttarget]Enterprise 2 using Client ID or Business Unit and saving to a folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, enterprise

Trying to create a folder or email in a Parent Folder within a Business Unit (clientID). We've learned that the Fuel API doesn't support Enterprise 2, but i'm hoping someone can point us to a reference on what a correctly formatted Create Request looks like for either folders and emails.

Trying to find any reference for what the soap object should look like to get this to work.
We get one of two errors: Folder Not found or an unknown error occured.
This is the Soap object we pass to ET.

```
(
    [CreateRequest] => Array
        (
            [Objects] => SoapVar Object
                (
                    [enc_type] => 301
                    [enc_value] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomerKey] => test_create_new_folder
                            [Name] => DEV ET FOLDER
                            [ContentType] => email
                            [ParentFolder] => Array
                                (
                                    [ID] => 2312
                                    [IDSpecified] => 1
                                    [ContentType] => email
                                )

                            [AllowChildren] => true
                            [IsEditable] => true
                            [ClientID] => 123456
                        )

                    [enc_stype] => DataFolder
                    [enc_ns] => http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI
                )

            [Options] => 
        )

)
===== RESULTS FROM \fuelsdk\ET_Post Object  ======
(
    [status] => 
    [code] => 200
    [message] => 
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [StatusCode] => Error
                    [StatusMessage] => ParentFolder with ID: "2312" could not be found.
                    [OrdinalID] => 0
                    [ErrorCode] => 396009
                    [NewID] => 0
                )

        )

    [request_id] => 
    [moreResults] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening, is that you have a `clientId` and `clientSecret` that are pointed at the top level enterprise business unit, and not one that points directly at the business unit you would need access to.

Start by creating a new application in AppCenter, and when you need to authenticate an account, add a new integration.  This time, you should see the following screen:

[image]

When you get to this stage, select the specific business unit, and finish the flow.

Use the newly generated `clientId` and `clientSecret` to access that business unit.